# Google MAP's GMSPlacePickerViewController : Not showing confirmation box like android in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I have implemented google's GMSPlacePickerViewController in one of my screen.

Now the issues is in Android they are showing confirmation box with selected location and location image like below,

[image]

Where in iOS they are not asking for the same, In iOS I have used below code,

```
// The code snippet below shows how to create and display a GMSPlacePickerViewController.
@IBAction func pickPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
  let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)

  present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// To receive the results from the place picker 'self' will need to conform to
// GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate and implement this code.
func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didPick place: GMSPlace) {
  // Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
  viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

  print("Place name \(place.name)")
  print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
  print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
}

func placePickerDidCancel(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController) {
  // Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
  viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

  print("No place selected")
}
```

Am I missing anything in above code?